# Sympy changes the random seed

Tags: python, random, sympy, random-seed, deap

I am working on a python 3 project where I use deap and sympy.
I set the seed to a fixed value after I imported the random module in the main file.py that I execute in order to have a reproductible code. but then I found out that I do not obtain the same results after I run it more than once (deap uses a lot of random numbers), when I tracked the bug I found that it's in the sympy parsing function sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr used to transform a string to a sympy expression. I am pretty sure sympy is messing with the random seed but I have no idea how to rectify it. Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated and let me know if the problem described is clear or not.
Thanks!

---

---

Comment: Could you post a [mre] that demonstrates the inconsistent-seed behavior you're describing?

Comment: Which version of SymPy are you using? A bug relating to this was fixed at some point so make sure you are using the latest version (1.10.1).

Comment: @OscarBenjamin oh I guess tha's why, I am using sympy 1.9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
As oscar said, apparently this was a bug that was fixed so all I needed to do was to update `sympy` to its latest version. If you already have Anaconda and want to update SymPy run the command:

```
conda update sympy
```